# Is this web scraping and is it legal?

Tags: web, screen-scraping

I have web-scraping related question. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything that answer in here or googling.

Ok, I might be involved in a project (site B) and am not sure about legality of it as to me it bordering on web scraping activities.

So there is site A which is an advertising site where people advertising various  items for sale etc. Would that be legal to contact advertisers via form on this particular site A and ask for permission to duplicate what they posted on site A, on another site B?

Now if user agreed to have his ad duplicated on site B, if this duplication would be performed automatically via scraping script, this would be illegal right?

What in situation if this duplication would be performed manually by the human. Someone would navigate to site A via web browser and duplicated so copied and pasted all the information that user posted there and posted this on site B?

The user who posted advertise would not have to do anything and would have to agree to have the content from site A duplicated to site B. That sounds fair to me. I'm only concerned about scraping automatically off site A. It would not happen often enough to have any impact onsite A, so Denial Of Service etc would be out of question but still I am not sure if that would be legal. Same if this was done manually I still have my doubts. Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping#Legal_issues? It might be of some help

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal concerns, not programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is web scraping and it would **not** be legal.

Generally when a person uses a listing service (web, newspaper, other) they agree to the terms and conditions of the service (the t&cs we all never bother to read). Those t&cs usually grant the service provider the full copyright over the listing. If they own the copyright you cannot use any part of the listing in your service. Including the person's photos, images and description of the item. (You would need to obtain the service provider's permission, which they would obviously not give to a rival service.)

E.g. a person wants to sell an item using a listing service. A picture is taken and uploaded and text added. The person owns the copyright to the picture and the typed text. The copyright of the listing as a whole and any pre-filled text strings (e.g. selected categories) is owned by the service provider.

Thus you cannot copy the listing or any part of it.

You can ask the person to up load their picture and their typed text separately to your service since they own the copyright of the original picture and text. Just not the copyright of it when used in the listing service.

I bet not many people know they sign away copyright when listing something for sale. For example here's a link to how an ebay user gives away their copyright:

http://pages.ebay.co.uk/help/policies/user-agreement.html#content

Comment: It may be against Terms of Use, but I don't think it will be illegal, in many countries.

Comment: Copyright is covered by the Berne Convention to which 167 countries are signed up. Copyright is covered by law, i.e. a legal issue. By listing an item you sign over copyright (even if you do not read the t&cs using a listing service implies you agree to them). So in 167 countries it would be illegal.

Comment: Copyright is copyright (which should be pretty clear in most countries), but the question was if the web scraping was illegal. Unless I misunderstand OP's post.

Comment: I read the question as relating to the whole scenario described, which would be illegal. Web scraping itself is not generally illegal (you could web scrap Wikipedia as the content is free to use as long as you respect the Creative Commons license). Some sites disallow automated access (e.g. web scraping) in their t&cs. In which case web scraping such as site would be against t&cs (a legal contract) and hence illegal.

Comment: I'm minded to agree slightly with @Nicolai, although you both make fair points. It would have been greatly helpful for the OP to have said what jurisdiction they fall under, and where their target site is; if they are both in, for example, the United States, the question of jurisdiction is easy. But if he or she is in China, the question of legality is a practical one - will it be enforced? For minor scraping, that would be unlikely.

Comment: The reason I'm hesitant to sign up to a hardline position on (il)legality is that one has to balance one's rights as an individual against the legal T&Cs that are (unfortunately) necessary to run an internet business. If I, for example, post an advert on Gumtree (i.e. eBay as parent company) do they have my explicit consent to remove my copyright ownership? Certainly not. Would they win a battle over content ownership in a court of law? Probably.

Comment: Someone should probably tell Google that their entire business model is illegal then - because this is exactly what they do, every second of every day...